Definition of improper integral, requirement or property?
I am confused about the definition of improper integral of more than one singularities, for instance, an improper integral of the form $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx $. From Wiki and some textbooks I read, it can be defined by as a pair of improper integrals $ \lim_{a \to -\infty} \int_{a}^{c} f(x) \, dx + \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{c}^{b} f(x) \, dx $, where $c$ is any convenient point at which to start the integration.
My question is whether 'the value of $ \lim_{a \to -\infty} \int_{a}^{c} f(x) \, dx + \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{c}^{b} f(x) \, dx $ does not rely on the choice of $c$' is a requirement or a property that can be proved.
If it is a requirement, can you give me an example, that the value of $ \lim_{a \to -\infty} \int_{a}^{c} f(x) \, dx + \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{c}^{b} f(x) \, dx $ does rely on the choice of $c$, so $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx $ does not exist?

It is a property. Show some attempt to prove it.

If both limits exist and are finite then their sum must be independent of the choice of $c$.

Suppose for $c'$, we have $\int _{-\infty}^{c'}$ and $\int ^{\infty}_{c'}$ both converge, I try to prove $\int _{-\infty}^{c}$ and $\int ^{\infty}_{c}$ both converge, where $c\neq c'$
WLO, I can suppose $c'>c$,
$\int _{-\infty}^{c'}+\int ^{\infty}_{c'}=\int _{-\infty}^{c}+\int _{c}^{c'}+\int ^{\infty}_{c'}=\int _{-\infty}^{c}+\int ^{\infty}_{c}$
